Migrate react native to expo
I have a bare react native project that is running for over 3 years.
I decided to migrate expo, I tried npx install-expo-modules@latest it worked but I want to keep my android and ios folder since I am using firebase messaging and also I have all the setup for deploying to stores.
is there a way? maybe a command similar to expo perbuild that keeps my current ios and android folders?

Whenever we need to add incompatible packages with expo go then follow the below procedures for development mode. This will automatically manage your ios and android folders, you won't have to do anything in these folders. Just follow below procedures. All you would have to do is add your firebase in app.json as plugin along with the path to your google services json file.

Make sure to have eas account and link with project by eas build:configure
npx expo install expo-dev-client
eas build --profile development --platform android /
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios --clear-cache
Install the generated build in your device
in project terminal run command npx expo start --dev-client
Enter the generated url in the enter url TextInput of your app

With these steps, you will be able to continue with your development as well as deployment, make sure you use your old SHA1 and JKS file in expo so that you can easily push updates to the same builds of the store.



I don't plan to use eas.


since react native project has already ios and android folders are you suggesting to delete them after migrating to expo?



You clearly mentioned you decided to migrate to expo. And for expo, you wouldn't require to manage android and ios folders seperately for integration of firebase. Above steps which I mentioned would just do the job for you.
